# What should be the value for learning rate and momentum?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, computer-vision

I am using around 250K images in total with 6 different labels and I am using VGG , with its last layer changed to accommodate 6 categories. What will be the value of learning rate and momentum if SGD optimiser is used?

Comment: Its a parameter you tune, not something you can ask someone else.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a lot of factor, including your training data, batch size, network... You should try different learning rates and see how fast they converge. The Keras `LearningRateScheduler` callback is also helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in fine-tuning, the learning rate is kept small. The convention used is 10x smaller than the learning rate used to train the model from scratch.

Momentum is used to dampen the oscillations in the optimization procedure. (when a reduction in one dimension is higher than the other dimension). Higher the momentum more forcefully the optimization procedure is forced to move in directions where the gradient is consistent (in direction) and dampens movement in directions where gradient direction changes. Default values are good to go.

Generally used values `lr = 1e-4, momentum=0.9`.